# What's the relationship between projects and applications in spinnaker?

Tags: spinnaker

In the latest UI of spinnaker, there are projects and applications labels. What's the relationship between projects and applications in spinnaker?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Projects provide an aggregated view of a collection of applications, but that's about it. If you're only interested in a subset of applications managed by Spinnaker, it's a decent way to manage them.

The relationship is modeled as many-to-many: a project is made up of one or more applications, and applications can be part of multiple projects.

Being in a project doesn't affect the application in any way, beyond making it present in the project view. There are no notifications to be configured at the project level, or pipelines that span multiple applications. You can set up a project pretty quickly and easily to get an idea what the view looks like.